# Setitng custom field values doesn't work with Paranoia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-paranoia

I have been trying to set up Paranoia with my project.  I have a `deleted_at` column and another column status which is equal to 2 when it's deleted.

Model Class

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_paranoid column: :status, sentinel_value: 1

  def paranoia_restore_attributes
    {
      deleted_at: nil,
      status: 1
    }
  end

  def paranoia_destroy_attributes
    {
      deleted_at: current_time_from_proper_timezone,
      status: 2
    }
  end 
end
```

But when I perform destroy or restore, it doesn't seem to change the status value.

Comment: Did you try [callbacks](https://github.com/radar/paranoia#callbacks) ? I think it will work.

Comment: What about this particular setup doesn't work?  Do you get any kind of error message?

Comment: @Makoto the `status` column does not get updated respectively

Comment: @ArupRakshit should i call them after setting up the above ? or different from this?

Comment: either of the 2 you can do.

Comment: @ArupRakshit any idea why this doesnt work. bcos this seems a better option since it will change both columns at once

Comment: @HarshaMV what error you are getting ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit no error. doesnt just happen

Comment: @HarshaMV I think I need to try out stuff if possible. Need to debug, why it is not working. It can be your fault or can be the gem author fault too.

Comment: What am trying to do  is . when ever the recorded is marked as `soft-delete` i am also changing the status between 1-2